# how to pick last 3 digits from the list of long decimal values

Tags: list, python-2.7, math, sequence

Below is the list of decimal numbers;

```
000000 =  0.0218354767535

000001 =  0.0218265654136

000002 = 0.0218184623573

000003 =  0.021811165579

000004 =  0.0218046731276

000005 =  0.0217989831063

000006 =  0.0217940936718

000007 =  0.0217900030345

000008 =  0.0217867094577

000009 =  0.0217842112574

000010 =  0.021782506802
```

I want to get the last three digits of each decimal number in list given. the following is my need in this example.

```
   535

   136

    573

    579

    276

    063

    718

    345

    577

    574

    802
```

any suggestions please for the possible solution?

Comment: These list of values are strings, is our understanding correct?

Comment: no these are float values ,i get it from graph ,these are values of "x" from first order differential equation,i did 500000 iteration and i want to pick last three digits from each element of array.

Comment: I have modified my answer to take input as list of float, and output as list of integers (last 3 digits of input float).

Comment: @pmaniyan can you please upvote my question. i will be thankful. my ban will be release .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the list given is a list of strings. In that case please use this code.

```
l1 = ["000000 =  0.0218354767535",
"000001 =  0.0218265654136",
"000002 = 0.0218184623573",
"000003 =  0.021811165579",
"000004 =  0.0218046731276",
"000005 =  0.0217989831063",
"000006 =  0.0217940936718",
"000007 =  0.0217900030345",
"000008 =  0.0217867094577",
"000009 =  0.0217842112574",
"000010 =  0.021782506802"]

for each_item in l1:
    print each_item[-3:]
```

**Modified Answer after receiving clarification**

```
result_list = [] # This would store the end result with int
# The below list is the input list with floats
l1 = [0.0218354767535,
0.0218265654136,
0.0218184623573,
0.021811165579,
0.0218046731276,
0.0217989831063,
0.0217940936718,
0.0217900030345,
0.0217867094577,
0.0217842112574,
0.021782506802]

#For each float in the list, find the decimal part, convert to string, extract last 3, convert to int and append to result list
for each_item in l1:
    result_list.append(int(str(each_item-int(each_item))[-3:]))

print result_list
```

**Output**

```
[535, 136, 573, 579, 276, 63, 718, 345, 577, 574, 802]
```

Answer (score 0):

For each line you can index only the last three elements like this:

```
with open('filename') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print line.rstrip()[-3:]
```

Comment: thanks for your help,but i need to pick the last three digits of each element from the array of 500000 values and put that lat three digits in another array or list,like if 
x=[1.2356565,2.3659856,.......,2.14589656]
result=[565,856,.......,656]
i need like this.can you assist me.
thanks